# Найти баг в программе с++

Tags: c++

Пишу программу на С++ в которую пользователь будет вводить день и месяц (год фиксированный - первый день года понедельник), а программа будет показывать день недели. Уже на этапе подсчета количества дней за предыдущие месяца столкнулся с неправильными цифрами (количество дней в месяцах находится в массиве `days_number`). Убил уйму времени, но так и не нашел где ошибка.
Вот сам код программы на данный момент:

```
// День недели по дате (месяц-день).cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". Здесь начинается и заканчивается выполнение программы.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string days_in_week[7] = { "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота", "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда" };//дни недели, они будут нужны мне позже
    int days_number[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };//количество дней в месяцах
    int days;
    int month;
    int result;
    int summa;
    cout << "Введите день, а затем месяц через пробел:\n" << endl;
    cin >> days;//вводится день
    cin >> month;//вводится месяц
    summa = 0;//ставим сумму дней месяца в положение 0
    for (int i = 0; i < days_number[month - 1]; i++)//начало цикла; должно посчитать дни всех месяцов до введеного пользователем не включая его
    {
        summa = summa + days_number[i];
    }
        cout << "Сумма:" << summa<< endl;
}
```

Пример ошибки: пользователь вводит день - 1. Пользователь вводит месяц - 2. Правильный результат будет - 59(31+28). Но программа выдает -1609084012.

Очень прошу вас о помощи. Пишу я на Visual Studio 2019, Windows 7

Comment: А почему для "день 1, месяц 2", правильный результат 59? Разве 1.2 это не первое февраля и номер у него не должен быть 32?

Comment: @nevilad пока что суммируются только дни месяцев не включая введенный. Массив начинается с нуля, то есть будут суммироваться два значения [0] и [1]. [2] который выбрал пользователь учитываться не будет

Comment: Т.е. месяц 2 это март?

Comment: Да, второй месяц - март

Answer (score 1):

Ну, меня терзают смутные сомнения в том, что вы выбрали верный путь... Тем более что

```
for (int i = 0; i < days_number[month - 1]; i++)
{
    summa = summa + days_number[i];
```

Итак, `month` у вас - 2. Т.е. цикл по `i` от 0 до 27 включительно.

Подумайте, чему равно, например, `days_number[i]` при `i` равном 20?

Comment: Так он же написал в вопросе, что это для фиксированного года.

Comment: >Подумайте, чему равно, например, days_number[i] при i равном 20?
Но ведь i максимум 12

Comment: @nevilad OK, просмотрел. Но все равно этого мало - надо еще указать, что год невисокосный :)

Comment: И все же я не понял что именно нужно поменять :(

Comment: Ну подумайте, пожалуйста! Что вы хотите суммировать? В каких пределах **должно** меняться значение `i`?

Comment: Допустим пользователь ввел month = 2 . По идее [і] должно сперва передать значение массива [0] (то есть 31) и присуммировать его к переменной summa. И так далее до элемента массива [1] включительно.

Comment: Пусть меня тут ругают за ругань, но тнельзя же быть таким тупыфм! `for(int i = 0; i < month-1; i++)`...

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Только начинаю кодить, простите..